# Failed to send request to error in ANT

Tags: ant

Getting this error when trying to retrieve package using ANT -

I have moved the ant-salesforce.jar file into the lib folder and I have set the proxy

> BUILD FAILED C:\ANT\build.xml:34: Failed to login: Failed to send
>   request to https://**--**.lightning.force.com/services/Soap/u/46.0

Using ant -verbose, it shows:

> dropping C:\ant-salesforce.jar from the path as it doesn't exist

What else do I need to check here to make this work?

Build.xml

```
    <project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
         so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
         will be treated literally.
    -->
    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../ant-salesforce.jar" />            
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- Test out deploy and retrieve verbs for package 'mypkg' -->
    <target name="test">
      <!-- Upload the contents of the "mypkg" package -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="mypkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
      <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
      <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="MyPkg"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Retrieve an unpackaged set of metadata from your org -->
    <!-- The file unpackaged/package.xml lists what is to be retrieved -->
    <target name="retrieveUnpackaged" depends="proxy">
      <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
      <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="sample/unpackaged/package.xml"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Retrieve all the items of a particular metadata type -->
    <target name="bulkRetrieve">
      <sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Retrieve metadata for all the packages specified under packageNames -->
    <target name="retrievePkg">
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="${sf.pkgName}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged and run tests in this organization's namespace only-->
    <target name="deployUnpackaged">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged" rollbackOnError="true"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Deploy a zip of metadata files to the org -->
    <target name="deployZip">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" zipFile="${sf.zipFile}" pollWaitMillis="1000" rollbackOnError="true"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows deploying code & running tests for code in directory -->
    <target name="deployCode">
      <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" directory, running the tests for just 1 class -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" rollbackOnError="true">
         <runTest>SampleDeployClass</runTest> 
      </sf:deploy>
    </target>

     <!-- Shows deploying code with no TestLevel sepcified -->
    <target name="deployCodeNoTestLevelSpecified">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows deploying code and running tests only within the org namespace -->
    <target name="deployCodeRunLocalTests">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" rollbackOnError="true"  testlevel="RunLocalTests"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows removing code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
    <target name="undeployCode">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="removecodepkg"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows retrieving code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
    <target name="retrieveCode">
      <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
      <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="codepkg" unpackaged="codepkg/package.xml"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows deploying code, running all tests, and running tests (1 of which fails), and logging. -->
    <target name="deployCodeFailingTest">
      <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" package, running all tests -->
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" testLevel="RunAllTestsInOrg" rollbackOnError="true" logType="Debugonly"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows check only; never actually saves to the server -->
    <target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
      <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" checkOnly="true"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows quick deployment of recent validation. Set the property sf.recentValidationId to your recent check only deployment Id -->
    <target name="quickDeploy">
      <sf:deployRecentValidation  username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" recentValidationId="${sf.recentValidationId}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Shows cancel deployment of deploy request either pending or in progress. Set property sf.requestId to Id of pending or in progress deploy request -->
    <target name="cancelDeploy">
      <sf:cancelDeploy  username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" requestId="${sf.requestId}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Retrieve the information of all items of a particular metadata type -->
    <target name="listMetadata">
      <sf:listMetadata username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Retrieve the information on all supported metadata type -->
    <target name="describeMetadata">
      <sf:describeMetadata username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="proxy">
        <property name="proxy.host" value="proxy-syd1.macbank" />
        <property name="proxy.port" value="8080" />
        <property name="proxy.user" value="" />
        <property name="proxy.pwd" value="" />
        <setproxy proxyhost="${proxy.host}" proxyport="${proxy.port}" proxyuser="${proxy.user}" proxypassword="${proxy.pwd}" />
 </target>  

</project>
```

build.properties file

```
# build.properties
#

# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sf.username = ****
sf.password = ****
sf.securitytoken = ****

#sf.sessionId = <Insert your Salesforce session id here.  Use this or username/password above.  Cannot use both>
#sf.pkgName = <Insert comma separated package names to be retrieved>
#sf.zipFile = <Insert path of the zipfile to be retrieved>
#sf.metadataType = <Insert metadata type name for which listMetadata or bulkRetrieve operations are to be performed>

# Use 'https://login.salesforce.com' for production or developer edition (the default if not specified).
# Use 'https://test.salesforce.com for sandbox.
# Use 'https://***.lightning.force.com' for dev
sf.serverurl = https://login.salesforce.com

sf.maxPoll = 20
# If your network requires an HTTP proxy, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html for configuration.
#
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your build.xml. We would need to see that to help.

Comment: @sfdcfox added in the post, please check

Comment: where are you defining the username/password and the login url?

Comment: Build.properties file

Comment: Can you provide your build.properties file?  (star out your username/password)

Comment: @NickCook added in the post, please check

Comment: Where is the 'ant-salesforce.jar' file relative to where you're executing the `ant` command?

Comment: @NickCook I have added a picture about the same, can you see it. I have kept the jar file inside lib folder inside ant, path = C:\ANT\apache-ant-1.10.6\lib, also tried keeping this out - path = C:\ANT

Comment: Your `ant-salesforce.jar` is in the same folder as the `build.xml`, which means you don't need the `../` in the `<pathelement location="../ant-salesforce.jar" />`

Comment: Hi @NickCook 1. I removed the jar file from the maine folder and let it just be in the lib folder -  didnt work. 2. jar file being in the same folder, reomoved ../ from xml file -  ``` <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-salesforce.jar" />         
        </classpath> ``` didnot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update the build.properties file

```
sf.src.username ='username'
sf.src.password = 'password'
```